# getting value from angular radio buttons

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I am trying to follow the angular docs for radio buttons.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D
Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Ultimately, I want the div "stuff" to have class "muted" if radio option 3 is selected.

**my html:**

```
<form name="shippingVm.MasterCartonForm" ng-controller="shippingControler as shippingVm" >

    [{{shippingVm.shipOption.val}}]

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
        <label class="radio-inline">
           <input type="radio" ng-model="shippingVm.shipOption.val" name="shippingOptions" ng-value="one" />
           I will call Purolator for a pickup.
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio"  ng-model="shippingVm.shipOption.val" name="shipOptions" ng-value="two" />
            I will deliver them to Purolator.
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="shippingVm.shipOption.val" name="shipOptions" ng-value="muted" />
            I will deliver them to the Wizmo warehouse myself.
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="ng-class="shippingVm.shipOption.val">
        stuff
    </div>

</form>
```

**my controller:**

```
vm.shipOption = {val: "NOT-muted"};
```

This debugging line in the HTML checks to see if I'm getting the right value:

```
[{{shippingVm.shipOption.val}}]
```

It starts with **[NOT-muted]** - as it should. But the moment I select any radio button it goes blank.

According to the docs, clicking a radio should pass the radio's **value** into the model.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ng-class is incorrect. See the below snippet for an example of what it should be. The second problem is that you want value instead of ng-value. From: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

> value The value to which the ngModel expression should be set when selected. Note that value only supports string values, i.e. the scope model needs to be a string, too. Use ngValue if you need complex models (number, object, ...).
>
> ngValue Angular expression to which ngModel will be be set when the radio is selected. Should be used instead of the value attribute if you need a non-string ngModel (boolean, array, ...).

```css
.muted {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <label>Chicken or the Egg?</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="chickenEgg" value="chicken" ng-model="formData.chickenEgg">Chicken
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="chickenEgg" value="egg" ng-model="formData.chickenEgg">Egg
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-class="{'muted': formData.chickenEgg === 'egg'}">
    stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see it now.

The radio buttons should have `value="muted"` not `ng-value="muted"`.

`ng-value` is only used in a special case.